# Is there a difference between changing the targetFramework version in the Visual Studio program properties and the vbproj file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, target-framework

I have tried to change the targetFramework version on the VS program properties from 4.0 to 4.5, and I got an error that I couldn't solve. Finally, I tried to change the version through the vbproj file of the program in the setting of "targetFrameworkVersion" and now the program works properly (also in the properties in VS the version has changed).

What is the difference between the two options and can I know for sure that the version has changed?

Comment: Can't say there is a difference for certain, however we recently moved from 4.0 to 4.8.1 and used this tool to do so which made it pretty simple. 
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PavelSamokha.TargetFrameworkMigrator

Comment: Most likely there is a bug in your VS installation and that's why trying to change it via the property pages failed. The property pages will read the value from the project file and changing the properties should modify the project file, but some sort of corruption in your installation will be preventing that.

Answer (score 0):

Both options should produce the same result.

When the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` tag of the project file is changed and saved, after rebuilding the project, you should successfully modify the target framework of the project.